# How to check the swap is on or off

Tags: linux

I know I can `swapon` and `swapoff` to turn the swap on and off.

But how can I check whether the swap is on or off currently.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23072/how-can-i-check-if-swap-is-active-from-the-command-line/537054

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cat /proc/swaps` for that.

```
<user>@<host>:~$ cat /proc/swaps
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda2                               partition       2098172 12820   -1
```

Comment: I know... If I swapoff, there is not item, or there is.

Comment: @LouXiu If swap is off then there shouldn't be an item listed.

Comment: There's also `swapon --show`